# Inserting data using a select

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do the following:

```
INSERT INTO job_additions (sor_no, sor_desc, invoice_no, qty, debit_credit)
VALUES
('CAR102008',(select sor_desc from sor_data where sor_no= CAR102008),'INV001002','2','d')
```

But I am getting an error of **Unknown column 'sor_desc' in 'field list'**

Is it possible to insert data that has been selected from another table?

Many thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
insert into job_additions (sor_no, sor_desc, invoice_no, qty, debit_credit)
select 'CAR102008', sor_desc, 'INV001002','2','d'
from sor_data 
where sor_no= 'CAR102008'
```